# I am making a txt file where if you input a word it opens a program and it opens the program if there is no word

Tags: python

it wont stop opening the program even if there is nothing in the txt file or nothing opens

```
import os

with open(r'file.txt'):
if "start" in 'file.txt':
    os.startfile(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\MinecraftLauncher.exe')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.
Currently your if statment is asking if "start" is in the string "file.txt" not in the file.

```py
import os
GAME_LOCATION = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\MinecraftLauncher.exe"
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    print(line)
    if "start" in line:
        os.startfile(GAME_LOCATION)
    else:
        print("start is not in the file")
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @loganRowe , 
you should put your code to this

```
import os
GAME_LOCATION = r'C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Minecraft Launcher"\MinecraftLauncher.exe'
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    if "start" in line:
        os.system(GAME_LOCATION)
    else:
        print("start is not in the file")
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE :**

> 1. Make sure your `file.txt` is on the same directory as your `.py` file
> 2. Make sure the directory of the launcher is valid

`"Program Files(x86)"` is needed because if you don't have it, the console will read as `Program Files(x86)` which had an error of a space between the 2 word